# Associated types on enum variants in rust

Tags: generics, rust, enums, associated-types

Imagine the following scenario: an Application can accept different kind of requests, processes them and returns either a response or and error. The different kinds of requests should be variants of an enum, such that we can match on them in a `processReqest` function. However each request type should have its own associated response and error types.
How can we achieve this in Rust?

```
trait ReqKind {
    type ResponseType;
    type ErrorType;
}

struct ImgReq {}
struct ImgRes {}
struct ImgErr {}

impl ReqKind for ImgReq {
    type ResponseType = ImgRes;
    type ErrorType = ImgErr;
}

struct TextReq {}
struct TextRes {}
struct TextErr {}

impl ReqKind for TextReq {
    type ResponseType = TextRes;
    type ErrorType = TextErr;
}

enum Requests {
    Img(ImgReq),
    Text(TextReq),
}

fn processReqest(r: Requests) -> ??? {
    match r {
        Requests::Img(_) => {
            return Ok(ImgRes);
            // or return Err(ImgRes)
        }
        Requests::Text(_) => {
            return Err(TextErr);
            // or return Ok(TextRes)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have so far, but I don't know how we would specify the return type of the processRequest function.

Comment: nit: Plurals in enum names are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using trait objects you can't return different types from a function depending on the input, since you're already using static dispatch for your input you can just unify the return types like you did with the `Requests` enum:

```rust
enum Response {
    Img(ImgRes),
    Text(TextRes),
}

enum Error {
    Img(ImgErr),
    Text(TextErr),
}

fn processReqest(r: Requests) -> Result<Response, Error> {
    match r {
        Requests::Img(_) => {
            return Ok(Response::Img(ImgRes));
            // or return Err(ImgRes)
        }
        Requests::Text(_) => {
            return Err(Error::Text(TextErr));
            // or return Ok(TextRes)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or to make use of the associated types just make your function a method on the trait instead:

```rust
trait ReqKind {
    type Response;
    type Error;
    fn process_request(&self) -> Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>;
}

impl ReqKind for ImgReq {
    type Response = ImgRes;
    type Error = ImgErr;
    fn process_request(&self) -> Result<Self::Response, Self::Error> {
        Ok(Self::Response)
    }
}

impl ReqKind for TextReq {
    type Response = TextRes;
    type Error = TextErr;
    fn process_request(&self) -> Result<Self::Response, Self::Error> {
        Err(Self::Error)
    }
}
```

Comment: but in this case, the Requests::Img(_) arm could theoretically return Response::Text(_) because there is no type level relation between Requests::Img and Response::Img. Do you know of any way to enforce this type security, using associated types?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need to generate an enum to for the error and for the response yourself. If there are many variants, or lots of enums, you can use the following macro to auto-generate them (it is not perfect, but it does the job and it is extendable):

```rust
macro_rules! generate_enum {
    {
        enum $name:ident ( $res_name:ident, $err_name:ident ) {
            $(
                $variant:ident ( $variant_ty:ty )
            ),* $(,)?
        }
    } => {
        enum $name {
            $(
                $variant ( $variant_ty ),
            )*
        }
        enum $res_name {
            $(
                $variant ( <$variant_ty as ReqKind>::ResponseType ),
            )*
        }
        enum $err_name {
            $(
                $variant ( <$variant_ty as ReqKind>::ErrorType ),
            )*
        }
        impl ReqKind for $name {
            type ResponseType = $res_name;
            type ErrorType = $err_name;
        }
    };
}

generate_enum! {
    enum Requests(RequestsRes, RequestsErr) {
        Img(ImgReq),
        Text(TextReq),
    }
}

fn processReqest(r: Requests) -> Result<RequestsRes, RequestsErr> {
    match r {
        Requests::Img(_) => {
            return Ok(RequestsRes::Img(ImgRes {}));
            // or return Err(ImgErr)
        }
        Requests::Text(_) => {
            return Err(RequestsErr::Text(TextErr {}));
            // or return Ok(TextRes)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while this generates a bunch of code it does no lead to any type level association between requests and responses. If I give a ImgReq to the processRequest() function I want to be sure to get back a Result<ImgReq,ImgRes>. With your approach, the `Requests::Img` arm of the match statement could still return an `Err(RequestsErr::Text(TextErr {}))` without any type errors

Comment: @TadeoHepperle True. I don't think you have a way to do what you want in Rust today, unless you can change the function to not take the enum but be generic.

Comment: okay, thanks a lot though. I hope something that will make this possible will be added in the future. I don't even know how to call this though. "Enum Traits"?

Comment: @TadeoHepperle I think this will require [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to discard `enum Requests` and convert `processRequest` to a `ReqKind` method:

```
trait ReqKind {
    type ResponseType;
    type ErrorType;

    // Add this `process` method to replace original *polymorphic* `processRequest` method
    fn process(&self) -> Result<Self::ResponseType, Self::ErrorType>;
}

struct ImgReq {}
struct ImgRes {}
struct ImgErr {}

impl ReqKind for ImgReq {
    type ResponseType = ImgRes;
    type ErrorType = ImgErr;

    fn process(&self) -> Result<Self::ResponseType, Self::ErrorType> {
        return Ok(ImgRes {});
        // or return Err(ImgRes)
    }
}

struct TextReq {}
struct TextRes {}
struct TextErr {}

impl ReqKind for TextReq {
    type ResponseType = TextRes;
    type ErrorType = TextErr;

    fn process(&self) -> Result<Self::ResponseType, Self::ErrorType> {
        return Ok(TextRes {});
        // or return Err(ImgRes)
    }
}
```

It should works in scenario that concrete types such as `ImgReq`, `TextReq` can be determined at compile-time. Using `enum Requests` to wrap them actually loses compile-time type information and has to check it at runtime.